# How to make sure `LazyVerticalGrid` is centered in the middle and as small as possible

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I got this code:

```
val emojis = listOf("A", "B")

Column {
    Text(text = "Hi")

    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(emojis.size),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        content = {
            this.items(items = emojis) {
                Text(text = it, style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6)
            }
        })
}
```

It gives me this result:

[image]

This is not what I want, I want that all items take exactly the amount of space they need and the layout should start in the middle, not `Start`.

Comment: Is the content in each cell a simple Text?

Comment: Can you also share a screenshot? "I want that all items take exactly the amount of space they need". Does this mean all cells are like wrap content (In this case it may be like a staggered grid), or each column with the widest text in it or all the cells having width of the widest cell?

Comment: @Abhimanyu Yea it's a `TextButton` actually, they should use wrap content indeed, they are all the same width.

Comment: You can use "GridCells.FixedSize" if all have a fixed width.

Comment: @Abhimanyu I don't know the width in advance

Comment: If all the cells have Text, you can calculate width of each cell using TextMeasurer and take the max of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it is possible to achieve with `LazyVerticalGrid` and not sure you need it as you set `columns = GridCells.Fixed(emojis.size)` - it means that all your items will be visible and placed on a single line like this:
[image]

If that's desired layout appearance - then simple `Row` is a better choice, as you won't use `LazyVerticalGrid` purpose: the layout in the picture above is not lazy and not vertical.

With `Row` usage, you can do the following:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Text(text = "Hi")


    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        //  modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
    ) {
        emojis.onEach { emoji ->
            Text(
                text = emoji,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I added `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()` to `Column` and `Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)` to the `Row` - by doing this, we have `Row`'s parent, `Column`, with screens width - it allows `Row` to start from the center as you asked in the question. Without that modifier on the `Column` - it will take as little width as its children need, and `Row` will be placed at the start of the screen.
Another approach is to add `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()` to the `Row` itself, and then it will take all available space (starting from the screens start, not center), and children will be centered in it thanks to `horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center` (`Column` doesn't need `fillMaxWidth` modifier then).

Comment: Thanks, it worked as a charm. I removed both `verticalAlignment` and `horizontalArrangement`, it worked without them.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that with the Lazy layouts. What you need is to create a custom layout which will measure the size of the children before setting the width of it. You can find how to do it over [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements).

If you already know approximately the width of the items, you can set a max and min width. It won't be exactly what you need but I think it's the closest you can get.

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(emojis.size),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Yellow).wrapContentWidth(unbounded = true).widthIn(min = 0.dp, max = 100.dp),
        content = {
            items(emojis.size) {
                Text(text = emojis[it], style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium, modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize())
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the emojis are the same size, and you can measure the width of an emoji, you can add a `modifier` to your `LazyVerticalGrid` to determine the width of the component with `emojis.size * emojiWidth`

```
val emojis = listOf("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")

val emojiWidth = 15
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
    Text(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Start), text = "Hi")

    LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = Modifier.width((emojis.size * emojiWidth).dp),
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(emojis.size),
        content = {
            items(emojis) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = it,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge.copy(
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold
                    )
                )
            }
        })
}
```

Will result in:
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyi1p.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :**

```
body: Center(
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 3 / 4, // Adjust the aspect ratio as needed
            child: LazyVerticalGrid(
              columns = GridCells.Fixed(emojis.size),
              horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
              verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
              content = {
                this.items(items = emojis) {
                  Text(text = it, style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6)
                }
              }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

The AspectRatio widget is then used to set the desired aspect ratio of the grid, which determines its width and height

Comment: Is that flutter code? The question is about kotlin-compose. Am I missing something?)

Comment: no, it is for kotlin compose

Comment: add aspectRatio:3 / 4, in your code